# Can I use one of Value's properties as a Key in a HashMap<Key, Value>

Tags: java, android

I have a calendar view widget with cells representing each day. Each cell has a Date object.
I also have a bunch of WorkDay objects that represent each date's work shift and schedule in hours. A WorkDay object has a Date in it.

I want to pass those WorkDay objects to the calendar , and when inflating the calendar, each cell should check which workday belongs to it by its Date object.

I don't want to foreach the group of WorkDay objects, I want to use keys instead.

My question is if I decide to use a HashMap to store the workdays,
can I use WorkDay's internal Date object as the key for each HashMap entry?

like so

```
hashMap.put(workDay.getDate(), workDay);
```

If this is not a good idea, what array/list/set/map structure should I use to store the WorkDay objects?

Comment: Sure, I see nothing wrong with that

Comment: The only problem you can have is on equals... hence if you have another data object with a couple of seconds later you will not find the workDay... maybe SimpleDateFormat the date to the measure that you need (hence key the String).

Comment: @PetterFriberg By the context of the question, I think he's more worried about what day it's on. There are tons of methods for relativity (from, before, after, ect...)

Comment: so long as the keys are unique

Comment: I do not necessarily need to use a HashMap. Any other way of traversing the WorkDay group by Date is fine with me as long as I don't have to foreach the collection each time because that would be inefficient

Comment: @PetterFriberg so you are saying that if I SimpleDateFormat the date to something like 02-28-2016 and use THAT as the key, I will be fine?

Comment: You bet (the key is that it need to equals...), maybe a nice way would be to create a getKey on your workDay and for example you return the new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(getDate())

Comment: @Vince Emigh, I was interpreting that maybe he means that he have a Date (from the calendar) and need to find his workDay object...., thats wyhy if he has two different date object (with millisec different) he will not find the workDay..

Comment: @PetterFriberg I think that is my answer. If you post it I will accept it

Comment: J.K post it yourself and accept... I'm not a rep hunter... have fun...

Comment: Sorry if I have offended you, didn't mean that. I've seen people say that in comments in other topics, so I emulated their behavior

Comment: You did absolute not offend me, I just like that OP have their own ideas and implementations... and if they have they can post it and accept it... if you don't like reputation points check community wiki and reefer to people that give you ideas in comments... Your question is not clear enough for me to post..... need to see more code and implementation to know which is the best answer..... so your answer is better then mine --- with hopes that you post a good answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I decided to do with the help of Petter Friberg.

I created this class:

```
public class DateKey {

    private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    private String dateKey;

    public DateKey(Date date) {
        dateKey = dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    public String getDateKey() {
        return dateKey;
    }

}
```

This class now serves as the key in my hashmap:

```
Map<DateKey, WorkDay> schedule = new HashMap<DateKey, WorkDay>();
schedule.put(new DateKey(workDay.getDate()), workDay);
```

Should I override equals and hashCode for this class?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, there is no problem using `Date` as the key of your `HashMap`, but design wise, you may want to use a Long representing the time in `ms`.

Doing so, your code become `Date` format agnostic (`dd.MM.yy`, `yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' hh:mm:ss z`, etc..), in more than storing a compact Object key (`Long`) in your Map.

You will also then be able to translate back this value into any kind of object you want, such as `Calendar`, java `Date`, joda time, etc..

It's also easier to store it in a Database, flat file system or whatever persistency you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `Date` object as a key in the `HashMap` whether it overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

From the [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) class documentation:

> More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)), then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)

If you want to retrieve your `WorkDay` objects correctly, you have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` accordingly.

Take a look at the documentation for these methods:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--